# vertical Menu functunality with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu (vertical menu) and i want each of the Ul's to show when hovering the dd's, and hide back in when mouseOut (second function of .hover()) what will be the best easiest way (without a plugin).

```
<dl class="lft-menubar">
<dt>Computers</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul class="slidedMenu">
         <li>3rd level menu</li>
         <li>3rd level menu</li>
         <li>3rd level menu</li>
         <li>3rd level menu</li>
         <li>3rd level menu</li>
         <li>3rd level menu</li>         
      </ul>
    </dd>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("dl.lft-menubar dd").hover(function () {
        $(this).next().show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).next().hide();
    });
</script>
```

Try something like that. :)

Comment: Thanks, but the code below is more correct (according to the example HTML)
   $("dd").hover(
    function (){
 $(this).children("ul").show();
 return false
 },
     function (){
    $(this).children("ul").hide()
  
 });

Comment: My mistake. I was looking at the relationship between the <dt> and the <dd> for some reason. Glad you figured it out though :)

Comment: by the way, how do i add the event as an parameter?  with the (e) in both functions? 

    $("dd").hover( function (e){ $(this).children("ul").show(); return false }, function (e){ $(this).children("ul").hide() })